# Manipulate and ParametricNDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate, evaluation

EDIT: typo spotted in comments, code reposted with fix as well as new behavior

I'm having trouble getting mathematica to give me a working plot. I've defined specific values for my parameters:

```
b = 0.1372; 
g = 1/7; 
soln = NDSolve[{X'[t] + b*X[t]*Y[t]/2700000 == 0, 
    Y'[t] - b*X[t]*Y[t]/2700000 + g*Y[t] == 0, Z'[t] - g*Y[t] == 0, 
    X[0] == 2700000 - Y[0], Y[0] == b*2700000, Z[0] == 0}, {X, Y, 
    Z}, {t, 0, 180}, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
Plot[{Evaluate[X[t] /. soln], Evaluate[Y[t] /. soln], 
  Evaluate[Z[t] /. soln]}, {t, 0, 180}, PlotRange -> {0, 3000000}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"S", "I", "R"}]
```

and got a good plot. I tried to scale this up for manipulate:

```
ClearAll;
soln = ParametricNDSolve[
   {
    X'[t] + b*X[t]*Y[t]/2700000 == 0, 
    Y'[t] - b*X[t]*Y[t]/2700000 + g*Y[t] == 0,
    Z'[t] - g*Y[t] == 0,
    X[0] == 2700000 - Y[0],
    Y[0] == b*2700000, 
    Z[0] == 0
    },
   {{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}},
   {t, 0, 500},
   {b, g}];
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  soln[b, g],
  {t, 0, 500},
  PlotRange -> {0, 3000000}
  ],
 {b, 0.01, .999},
 {g, 0.01, .999}
 ]
```

and nothing fruitful came out. The sliders show up, but the plot window is highlighted red, and I get error output:

```
ParametricNDSolve::dspar: 1 cannot be used as a parameter.

ParametricNDSolve::dspar: 1.` cannot be used as a parameter.

ParametricNDSolve::dspar: 1 cannot be used as a parameter.

General::stop: Further output of ParametricNDSolve::dspar will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Comment: try `ParametricNDSolve` and not `ParamatricNDSolve` and see if that works. When the color is blue it means Mathematica does not know about it.

Comment: Will update original post, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why you want to use `ParametricPlot` in the `Manipulate`, while you had used `Plot` in your first visualization. Consider that you have three components in your solution, so that would not make sense for a 2D parametric plot; you would have to use `ParametricPlot3D` instead. I suspect that neither are what you want, and instead you simply want plots of the three components as a function of the $b,g$ parameters, in which case `Plot` will do.

Here are a few modifications that at least allow you to see the shape of the results. In particular, I changed to [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) and I removed one level of braces in your desired result (i.e. `{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}` and not `{{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}}`. I then used `Plot` instead of `ParametricPlot` inside `Manipulate`.

```
ClearAll[b, g, t, soln]
soln = ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] + b*X[t]*Y[t]/2700000 == 0, 
    Y'[t] - b*X[t]*Y[t]/2700000 + g*Y[t] == 0, Z'[t] - g*Y[t] == 0, 
    X[0] == 2700000 - Y[0], Y[0] == b*2700000, Z[0] == 0}, 
    {X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}, {t, 0, 500}, {b, g}];

Manipulate[
  Plot[Evaluate@soln[b, g], {t, 0, 500}, PlotRange -> {0, 3000000}],
  {{b, 0.05}, 0.01, .999}, {g, 0.01, .999}
]
```

[image: colored plots of the three solutions]

I chose a starting value for `b` that would give a more interesting / pleasing plot, but that adds nothing to the functionality.

Comment: This is wonderful and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This is a great answer! Sorry I accidentally downvoted it, it’s now locked in and I can’t adjust the vote. This is a strange pattern for me (mobile browsing when too tired, hah!). This would look really cool in 3D!

Answer (score 1):

For simulation purposes, one can use the following code with a button to generate different sets of parameters at the same time rather than changing individual parameters. The example uses "Initialization" to change parameters (k1,k2,k3,k11,k22) at the same time. Press `Button` to generate new parameter values for (k1,k2,k3,k11,k22) based on `Initialization`.

```
Clear[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]];
Clear[eqns, init, vars, param, solNL];

eqns = {
y1'[t] == -k1*y1[t]*y2[t] + k11*y3[t],
y2'[t] == -k1*y1[t]*y2[t] + k3*y5[t] + k11*y3[t],
y3'[t] == k1*y1[t]*y2[t] - k2*y3[t]*y4[t] + k22*y5[t] - k11*y3[t],
y4'[t] == -k2*y4[t]*y3[t] + k22*y5[t],
y5'[t] == k2*y3[t]*y4[t] - k22*y5[t] - k3*y5[t],
y6'[t] == k3*y5[t]
};
init = {
y1[0] == 30,
y2[0] == 1,
y3[0] == 0,
y4[0] == 20,
y5[0] == 0,
y6[0] == 0
};
vars = {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6};
param = {k1, k2, k3, k11, k22};

solNL = ParametricNDSolveValue[
{eqns, init},
vars,
{t, 0, 20},
param
];

Manipulate[
Plot[
Evaluate[#[t] & /@ solNL[k1, k2, k3, k11, k22]], {t, 0, 20}, 
PlotLegends -> vars
],
Button["generate new parameters", {k1, k2, k3, k11, k22} = random[]],
Initialization :> (random[] := {RandomReal[{1, 2}], 
 RandomReal[{1, 2}], RandomReal[{2, 5}], RandomReal[{2, 8}], 
 RandomReal[{2, 4}]}; {k1, k2, k3, k11, k22} = random[];)
]
```